# Yeoman Generated Angular Project Imported into IntelliJ -> Huge Mess

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, yeoman-generator

The project generated looks pretty nice. But IntelliJ finds a socket.io/flash app in node_modules and tries to make a module out of that. But the app folder is not there.

Think this is based on the angular seed. Can't believe no one has tried to do this though.

Answer (score 2):

Only option is to create an empty idea project and move all the folders there. Or else you'll have to use Webstorm.

Comment: +1 This did the trick for me. New project->Static Web->Static Web, then yo angular to build the scaffold.